# Will automatic routing happen?

Tags: networking, routing

What will happen, if I set old-fashion no-nat router Unix between 3 networks, 2 internet ones and 1 my subnet, like here:

[image]

Settings are default: each subnet has proper gateway ans mask setup. Routing is enabled.

First suppose I bought subnet at left. What will happen? Will traffic walk and load ballance between Internet 1 and 2 or no?

Next what will change if I see my subnet to 192.168.0.x?

Comment: If your subnet is routed in the internet, there might be some "balance" between the two internet routes, depending on configuration and metrics. If your subnet is `192.168...`, it won't work, as private subnets are not routed in the internet (what makes them 'private').

Comment: Will packets travel from `Internet 1` to `Internet 2` and vice versa?

Comment: Usually they won't, as there had to be routing information through your box in internet (providers don't accept that). Do you want to be the 'man in the middle'?